# Is there a significant disadvantage in allowing a computer with a solid-state boot drive to use the pagefile?

Tags: performance, memory, ssd, computer-building

I have been working on putting together a build for my next computer, one one of the items I would like to include is an [OCZ Vertex Series 30GB SSD](http://www.newegg.com/Product/Product.aspx?Item=N82E16820227393).

My build will be using DDR2 RAM, but while deciding on parts, an interesting thought struck me.  As the SSD is to be used solely as a boot drive, and because SSDs have such impressive read/write times, is there any pressing need to buy enough RAM that my computer will not often need to access the pagefile?

What would the difference in speed be between reading/writing from this SSD and PC2-8500 RAM?  Considering that I have a tight budget, would it be worth saving $50 by buying 1x2GB as opposed to 2x2GB?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> What would the difference in speed be
>   between reading/writing from this SSD
>   and PC2-8500 RAM?

SSD:

```
Sequential Access - Read   Up to 230 MB/s
Sequential Access - Write   Up to 135MB/s
Sustained Write: Up to 80MB/s
```

RAM:

```
Peak Transfer Rate: 8533 MB/s
```

with these factors aside, I'd buy the RAM regardless. Processing & accessing data from memory is much faster than accessing the disk.